# Recursive pointer function

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, singly-linked-list

I am struggling to implement a method called find_set within my class blob.  It is a recursive function which returns pointer to a blob object. My blob class is basically a linked list and this function is supposed to be passed a blob and then recursively traverse blob's parents until arriving at the head of the blob list. 
I am at work so I am having to recreate the essentially components.  This is not copy and pasted version of my code, but I want to know how to do it by the time I get home.

```
class blob{

public:
int size;
int index[2];
char value;
blob *parent;
blob *find_set(blob* &in_question);
};
```

The necessary elements of the blob class to understand my conundrum.

```
blob* blob::find_set(blob* &in_question){
if(in_question!=nullptr)
   in_question.parent= find_set(&in_question.parent);
return in_question;
}
```

I hope I have been explicit enough.

Comment: _find_set_ could be declared _static_: `static blob *find_set(blob* &in_question);`

Comment: Why are you modifying the blob as you're searching through it? Searching is usually not a destructive operation.

Comment: This is a disjoint data structures method.   The search travels up the link list until reaches the head and then points all the nodes traversed at the at the head so that the search time for subsequent searches is decreased.

Comment: @ninjaneer12 Interesting. You can add that to the question to avoid more pointless comments like mine. ;-)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks.  I am new here.  I'm getting better at asking questions.

Comment: @ninjaneer12 Don't get discouraged. Welcome to the land of StackLords and StackGods. They love to ANONYMOUSLY knock down (=downvote) the newbies. But I upvoted and favorited you to encourage you.

Comment: @Goodbye  hahaha, I sensed that.  I appreciate your encouragement. I'll stick with it.  I can handle a little condescension in exchange for nearly instant amazing help. :)

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm guessing the problem is here:

```
blob* blob::find_set(blob* &in_question){
if(in_question!=nullptr)
   in_question.parent= find_set(&in_question.parent);
return in_question;
}
```

I'm not quite sure why you're taking a reference to a pointer, but here's a working version of the code:

```
blob* blob::find_set(blob* in_question){
    if(in_question != nullptr)
       in_question->parent = find_set(in_question->parent);
    return in_question;
}
```

- Accessing members of a pointer requires using `->` instead of `.`
- Taking the address of `in_question->parent` yields an object of type `blob**`, which is probably not what you want

Comment: oooooh I probably read a 10 times on cplusplus.com  but It did not occur to me that it was both necessary and sufficient to do so.  I need to pass in the pointer not a copy of the pointer.  Is that accomplished by virtue of the fact that I'm passing in a pointer?

Comment: Am I missing something obvious here, or wouldn't this, and the original code, not just return a copy of the input?

Comment: @ninjaneer12 Yes; because you're passing in a pointer, now don't really need to pass it by reference. You're assigning to an attribute of the pointer, not the pointer itself.

Comment: @Jaciq what you are missing is that what is being passed is the parent blob.

Comment: But aren't you just setting the parent? If for instance we have two blobs, A and B, with A being B's parent and we call the function on B, the following would be the result of the initial if statement, assuming A's parent is null.

return null; --- A->parent = null; --- return A; --- B->parent = A; --- return B;

Shouldn't you instead return find_set(in_question_>parent), just as the other answer suggests?

Comment: @Jaciq Well, I was assuming that something else would end up being inserted and that this was incomplete code...

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the method is to get the "top blob", i.e. the blob that has no parent, I would change the name to *get_top_blob* or similar.

Naming aside, you need to change the recursion termination condition so that the last recursion call actually returns the "top blob" (currently, the last call returns *nullptr*).

```
blob* blob::get_top_blob(blob* in_question){
    if(in_question == nullptr) //no blob -> no "top blob"
        return nullptr;
    else if(in_question->parent != nullptr) // get the "top blob" of the parent
        return get_top_blob(in_question->parent);         
    else //in_question is the "top blob"
        return in_question;
}
```

**Update:**

Or, in case you wish to "flatten" the tree at the same time (see the Enhancements section
 in [Disjoint set data structure (C)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Disjoint_set_data_structure_(C)). They're not using recursion and thus their code is easier to read IMO. And now that you have clarified the context, their naming is probably better than what I suggested)

```
blob* blob::get_top_blob(blob* in_question){
    if(in_question == nullptr) //no blob -> no "top blob"
        return nullptr;
    else if(in_question->parent != nullptr) // get the "top blob" of the parent
    {
        top_blob = get_top_blob(in_question->parent);
        in_question->parent = top_blob;
        return top_blob;
    }   
    else //in_question is the "top blob"
        return in_question;
}
```

Comment: It is called find set because the context is a forest of disjoint trees.  The function finds the root node of the tree, the representative of the set, in the forest.

Comment: I appreciate the first if though it was definitely something I was going to have to add.

Comment: [You forgot your braces in the last example](https://gradha.github.io/articles/2015/04/whitespace-goto-fail.html).

Comment: @Kim Hansson Oh man I didn't see your response until now!! aaaaaaaaaaah!  I have been killing myself over this program, and I didn't even pull off the flatten part!  Either way I am learning c++!

Answer (score -1):

This is what the member function find_set(...) looked like after I got it working.

```
blob *blob::find_set(blob &in_question){
    if(in_question.parent!=nullptr)
        in_question.parent= find_set(*in_question.parent);
    else
        std::cout<<"("<<in_question.index[0]<<","<<in_question.index[1]<<")"<<std::endl;
    return in_question.parent;
}
```

Comment: The last recursion call still returns _nullptr_.